# Iterating through a map with one key and a pair of values

Tags: c++

I have this map and assumed that it's already filled with datas.

`map<string,pair<int,int> >mymap;`

Lets say it has key and a pair of values that looks like this:

ex:
`"Hello", {10,20};`

I already know how to output with one key and one value.

[std::map one key, two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560573/stdmap-one-key-two-values) it's shown here that you can have one key with 2 values but i don't know how to iterate through them and get an output like in the example.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Each `pair<int,int>` in the map *is **one** "value"*.

Comment: And if you know how to iterate over a map using iterators or a range-for loop, then you have already encountered `std::pair` since each element in a map is a `std::pair`, wich a `first` and a `second` element.

Comment: This is the first one that i have used ```for(map<string,int>::iterator i = mymap.begin(); i != mymap.end(); i++) {
    cout << i -> first << ", " << i -> second << endl;
  }``` for iterating one key and one value. What do you think should I change?

Comment: With the map `map<string,pair<int,int>>` then `*i` is a `pair<string, pair<int, int>>`. I.e. `i->first` is a `string` value, and `i->second` is a `pair<int, int>` value. Now think a little bit, a pair is a pair is a pair, and it will always have a `first` and a `second` member. How do you think that the first and second integers of the value pair could be accessed?

Comment: Thanks for the infos. I already solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

So this worked for me.

I first i initialized these.

```
pair<int,int> pairs;
map<string, pair<int,int> > mymap;
```

then using a for loop.

```
pairs.first = //some integer;
pairs.second = //some integer; 
mymap[ //here i used the values from an array so i used array[current_index] ] = pairs;
```

for the output.

```
for(auto i : mymap) {
    //i.first for the key
    //i.second.first and i.second.second for the pair values
}
```

sources that i read:

[Iterate over vector of pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606108/iterate-over-vector-of-pair) ,
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/insert/

Please do notify me. Maybe i'm incorrect with this one.